# error de sintaxis en mi codigo de APIs

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Estoy intentando utilizar un API para enriquecer mi DB.Este es mi código y me da un error de sintaxis en los puntos de 'Authorization',he construido mi función a partir de otro código.

````
``def getFromRAPI(endpoint, queryParams={}):
    url = f"https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com{endpoint}"
    querystring = {"tconst":"tt0944947"}
    apiKey = os.getenv("RAPIKEY")
    if not apiKey:
        raise ValueError("Please setup the RAPIKEY env variable")
    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com"
        'Authorization' : f"token {apiKey}"
    }
    
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(res.url)
    return res.json()``

```import requests

url = "https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/title/get-top-cast"

querystring = {"tconst":"tt0944947"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': ""
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)```
````

Comment: puedes mostrar el error que te arroja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te falto poner la coma antes de 'Authorization' asi

```
headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com",
        'Authorization' : f"token {apiKey}"
    }
```